# Does "platform-api" depend on the Ubuntu distro?

Tags: 14.04

The Ubuntu architecture has a layer named `platform-api`. Does this layer depend on the Ubuntu distro? For example, does `platform-api` on UbuntuTouch differ from `platform-api` on the regular 64-bit Ubuntu desktop?